# Why is stylesheet only working for the index page, but not for any extensions of the index page? (templates using Jinja)

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

As I said in the title; I am making a basic blog using Django, and while I have a basic line of code that ties the CSS stylesheet to the index of the blog; this works just fine, but whenever I link to any template of said index sheet the stylesheet does not seem to roll over onto the template.
In other words, the template does not have any CSS applied to it, unlike the index sheet.

I am using Jinja2 template sequencing.

This is the current HTML line linking the stylesheet:

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css" />`
```

This is the template in question:

```
{% extends 'tempblog/index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br /><br /><br />Hi!
{% for post in latest_posts %}
<ul>
<br /><br />
<li>
{{ post.title }} </li><br /><br /> {{ post.body }}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also please note that the template is displaying all database calling just fine, this is a matter of the stylesheet only working on the index, and not on any extension of the index page. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `style.css` file in  a folder called `static`, relative to the index?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by relative; but the index file is in a separate (same level) folder called "templates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative URL for the stylesheet; you need to prepend a forward slash so that it's relative to the root and not the page being viewed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css" />
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Thank you. Now I need to read more about a relative URL, because I didn't even know that existed. I thought that that was classified as a typo.